# Image not being Shown for Flutter AppBar

Tags: flutter

The images for the code below are not showing and it's throwing an exception. My pubspec is aligned correctly so not sure what's wrong.

I tried updating flutter, restarting,re-aligning but still get the same exception below.

> Syncing files to device iPhone X... flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY
>   IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
>   ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ flutter: The
>   following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec: flutter:
>   Unable to load asset: /images/barlogo.png flutter: flutter: When the
>   exception was thrown, this was the stack: flutter: #0
>   PlatformAssetBundle.load
>   (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7) flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(
      MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: new Color(0xffA62FF0),
              centerTitle: true,
              elevation: 1.0,
              leading: new Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              title: SizedBox(
                  height: 35.0, child:new Image.asset('/images/barlogo.png')),
              actions: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                  child: new Image.asset('/images/search.png'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
      )
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception gives it away - Flutter cannot find the image requested.

You should not have a leading `/` when specifying asset paths. Try:

```dart
Image.asset('images/barlogo.png')
```

There's more info in the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html

Comment: btw do you know if there's a way to add an image as the background for the AppBar

Comment: Probably better to open a new question with more information about what you're trying to achieve - there are several places you an put an image into the AppBar.